# Request access token from Instagram API

Tags: json, curl, token, instagram

I've been told to put this in my Command Promt terminal:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

I'm using Windows, and have installed curl, for the command to work in my OS. However, i get this error:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '\'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '\'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '\'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '\'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '\'
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "You must 
provide a client_id
```

I have provided a client_id, and yet is tells me to provide it...
I'm supposed to get a JSON Object after this.
I don't know why this is happening. Please help me.

Comment: Remove the `\\` and do everything in one line.

Comment: Thanks, raam86. It seems to work fine. The only error that I sitll get is that, although I have typed the client_id, I still get the message: "You must provide a client_id". I've been wasting a lot of time trying to solve this, but I can't.

Comment: read the error message, `curl` thinks that the `\\` is the url

Comment: It could've been when it had the back slash, but, even when removed, the command prompt still displayed the same error. I'm gonna look for another way around. But I really appreciated your help. :)